# Customizing preamble.tex in bookdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I started using bookdown to generate a longer report, but came into some touble as I wanted to customize the pdf output.  `\documentclass[]{}` does not work in the `preamble.tex` file. I think that comand is somehow executed by pandoc beforhand, unfortunately I did not find out how to pass options to it so far.

I worked around a few things like setting the fontsize via  `\usepackage[12pt]{moresize}` but I was wondering how to acces the set up options properly. The bookdown documentation does not cover this subject in sufficient detail for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [BookDown Documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/latexpdf.html),

You can just add following in your header yaml,

```
---
documentclass: book
bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
---
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the [Pandoc documentation](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex)